# My code giving the same expected output but tester is marking It incorrect?

Tags: c, loops

I have posted my code below which is in fact giving the same output as expected. Please help me with this problem as I am constantly experiencing this type of problems in other platforms also such as HackerRank and HackerEarth etc...I think this type of problems arises as the tester instead of Evaluating the Final output evaluates the Code thereby limiting the scope of Creativity. I am currently a beginner in coding; any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Expected pattern]
[image: my code output]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int i = 1,j,x;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    x = num - 1;
    printf("Input number is %d.\n", num);
    for(i = 1;i <= num;i++)
    {
        if((i == 1) || (i == num))
        {
            for(j = 1;j <= num; j++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
            x--;
        }
        else
        {
            for(j = 1;j <= x; j++)
            printf(" ");
            printf("*");
            printf("\n");
            x--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The two images look different to me. The one on the right has `Input number is 5`, but the other does not. Have you tried removing the print statement?

Comment: Make sure to read the problem statement carefully. Some will explicitly tell you not to print a newline after the last line. Some you will get a wrong answer and have to experiment.

Comment: You have an extra line in your output, which is `Input number is 5.`  Get rid of it.